# Handling clicks with achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using the chartview with achartengine to display a daily mood tracker. The points on the chart are populated from a local database. Each point on the chart is clickable. However, there are many more potential points (minutes of the day) than actual points (when the user added to their diary). This makes it very difficult to actually register the onclick events when using the phone. It works fine in the emulator, but that's because a mouse is more exact than a thumb. Does anyone have any advice on how to make the points in a chartview easier to click? (I.e., is there a way to spread everything out; should I just compress the potential points into hour by hour, instead of minute by minute, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it .... it's .setSelectableBuffer(int buffer)